# Max proximity for dinosaur dossier unlock

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

Last night I tamed a philomia but was far enough away that when it became tame the dossier didn't appear on the screen. How close must you be to receive credit for taming the dinosaur?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an exact numerical value as there is no way to measure or know that in-game.

As a rough guideline, from personal experience and observation, I would say you ought to be no further away than about 30-40 feet max to be safe (and claim the dossier entry).